# Boot Linux from UEFI BIOS

Tags: linux, boot-loader, bios

I'm porting UEFI BIOS. I'd like to download an Linux image (bzImage) to system memory by TFTP in my UEFI shell, and then boot the OS directly. I know we generally need another bootloader to do that. But is it possible to boot Linux in UEFI BIOS? And how?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779

Comment: You may find Matthew Garrett's (recently formerly of RedHat) adventures with UEFI useful: http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20187.html

Answer (score 2):

A UEFI firmware (not BIOS, that's something else) can only load UEFI applications corresponding to the EFI firmware architecture. So you can't directly load a Linux kernel, but you should be able to load a [UEFI bootloader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_loaders) which will then load the Linux kernel into memory and jump to it.

#### Since kernel version 3.3

It become possible to compile a Linux kernel with the EFISTUB option, which allows to directly execute/load the kernel as an EFI image without having to use a boot loader.

Comment: Is it possible to do what UEFI bootloader does in UEFI BIOS?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes but firstly you need to enable the network card so that your target machine can ping the FTP server to get the kernel image.

Checkout the [EDK Boot Loader (EBL) WiKi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tianocore/index.php?title=EDK_Boot_Loader_%28EBL%29_WiKi) SourceForge link.

Comment: EBL looks like not booting a Linux bzImage...