# Installing Arch Linux with UEFI Boot and GPT Layout

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

I'm trying to set up a dual UEFI boot Windows/Arch Linux, and have already installed Windows on a GPT layout through UEFI boot. I now want to fresh install Arch Linux using GPT layout as well, and was wondering how I could do that.

More specifically, do I need to modify the content of the core install image to be able to boot from it in UEFI?

If I manage to boot in UEFI from the core install image, will it automatically set up my partitions using GPT layout?

I've read a couples of tutorial on how to set up UEFI boot with Arch, but it seems most of them considered only a situation were Arch Linux was already installed (using MBR layout?)

Thank you

Comment: It's pretty much the same in Debian and Arch, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to boot Arch from UEFI by using an Archboot image, and then install it on the GPT drive. Then I had to install grub2, which I installed on the same partition as the Microsoft EFI partition, and chainloaded Windows 7 bootloader from it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello,
I'm currently trying to do the same as you, could please give some links that helped you to solve your problem ? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I don't have them anymore, sorry. Did you make any progress since then?

Comment: I installed it using MBR. x)

Comment: Aw. So no GPT? How did you deal with partitions alignment?

Comment: I just formated my hard drive and installed Arch. Since I don't use Windows anyway, I didn't see the point in trying to have it on my computer. So MBR was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works quite well as long as you follow [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) steps...be sure to read carefully regarding `/boot` and `/boot/efi`, and how you want to mount them.