# Can't boot live USB of Linux Mint DE on my UEFI PC

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, live-usb, uefi

I used the Universal USB Installer application to copy the latest ISO image from Linux Mint DE  (64 bits) and install it on my PC, however when I try to reboot it I have the option to choose my connected USB device as "UEFI: ... USB ..." but when I choose it it doesn't do anything, the screen goes black for a couple seconds then loads windows 7 normally.

Should I do something before trying to boot into the USB device? This is my first time trying to install a linux distro on a UEFI-based PC I never had a problem like this before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not address you particular problem, but might be helpful: [Information about how to set up Debian on UEFI](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779)

Comment: I see, so maybe I need a `.efi` file in the USB to be able to boot it? I was browsing the files and there's no EFI folder or anything like that

Comment: No you don't need any .efi, read my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues where unetbootin didn't set the correct volume label; some distributions expect to be able to mount the volume by volume label.

I've gotten around this by using the `dd` utility to copy the entire filesystem from the `.iso` to the USB drive.

For example, if the USB is at `/dev/sdc` and your Linux Mint installation image is at `/home/me/mint.iso`:

```
dd bs=4m if=/home/me/mint.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

The `of` argument tells it the output file to write to, so make sure you point it at the right drive - and make sure you point it at the volume itself, not a partition like `/dev/sdc1`.

I've personally booted from Linux isos on EFI systems using this method and it's been fine.

Comment: Sounds good, however since I haven't been able to install or even boot the live cd of any linux distro due to this uefi problem I can't use the `dd` command (currently on win7) do you have any idea how I should do it?

Comment: Nvm, I was able to boot a live usb image of ubuntu 12.10 and tried your suggestion, still the problem persists :(

Comment: Remember to use `oflag=direct` and `sync` after `dd` when writing to USB sticks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not mount your ISO to your USB. You can use something like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to mount it. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I did but I had the same problem, [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) works pretty much the same anyways

Comment: Oh, forgive my ignorance. Have you tried (Care to try?) other versions of Linux Mint?

Comment: No worries, I tried the regular version 14 but same outcome..

Answer (score 0):

You should do a couple of changes in your BIOS. First you should disable Safe Boot mode, look for it in your BIOS, then you should activate CSM to let all the boot devices be visible (at least in my asus x550c) then disable fast boot. I think with those changes you should be ready to go. Wipe your F*?-ng Windows and install that linux distro you are willing to install.

In case you want to keep your windows, I think you will have to do a couple more changes otherwise your grub won't boot, but I didn't get that far, I just wiped all windows 8.x partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had been having frustrating times trying to use a once-easy method
 of thumbdrive booting with different hardware arrangements, and was
 very glad to have the specifics spelled out for me upon discovering
 the "Notes about bootability" section of this posting:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick (which
 essentially lays out how finnicky different hardware is.)  I think
 this will address your issue.

I saw a great UEFI multi-bootingtutorial in a Linux magazine a year or more ago..  it would have either been Linux Format or possibly Linux Pro ..?  (I heard on a podcast that Linux Voice might be closing.. a shame!  They offer all issues free online once they've aged 9 mos.)

Comment: Please revise this answer as it's currently of doubtful quality.  Chit-chat, and unrelated comments aren't suitable for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I used Pinguy Builder (as alternative to Remastersys, which is not available) to create a custom disc of my Linux Mint 18.3. I used the built-in USB Image writer to make a live USB. It worked with all UEFI-based PCs.