# Installing the kernel EFI stub loader in kernel 3.2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, uefi

Kernel EFI stub loader support was added in kernel 3.3, but I'm stuck on 3.2 running an Ubuntu 12.04 64bit distribution. Is there a way for me to somehow bring that stub loader support into my kernel?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use a 3.3 kernel (probably custom built, I don't know if Ubuntu ships with EFI stub by default). Would that be an option?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking into that now. I'm probably going to go straight to kernel 3.7, as I need fixes implemented in kernel 3.6.

Comment: Do you know where I can get Ubuntu's config and Module.symvers files for building a kernel? I want to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu, but on Debian the config is included in the `linux-image-XYZ` binary package. If you need build instructions, [here are the necessary steps to install Debian on an UEFI system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779). The guide works for Ubuntu as well.

Comment: It could be located in those packages on Ubuntu, too.

Comment: Debian has backported EFI stub support for 3.2 kernel. It's enabled by default. Check your /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply installing a later kernel. You'd be surprised how easy this is. Simply searching packages.ubuntu.com for kernel packages allowed me to find the packages I needed. I needed to install essentially `linux-image-3.X.*`, `linux-image-extra-3.X.*`, and `linux-headers-3.X.*`. Posting from a nice, shiny EFI-booting Linux.