# Cent OS 6.4 UEFI Dual boot

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I have Windows 8 installed on UEFI BIOS. When i installed Cent OS, installation went smoothly and then after restarting, Windows booted normally like there's no Linux installed.

I know it's something to do with UEFI, but i really cannot figure it out, i tried to boot from Hard drive instead of "OS.. something" inside the BIOS Boot Order, but i get blinking cursor nothing more.

**NOTE**

For partitions i've created two partition normally like i always do before using UEFI.. `ext4` drive for `/` and `swap` drive.

Can anybody tell me how to dual boot while using UEFI ?

Comment: Does your system's BIOS have secure boot enabled? I believe that needs to be disabled.

Comment: @slm i've checked, it's not even active to change. it's dimmed, but it's set on `disabled`

Comment: When booting the CentOS DVD did you happen to boot the DVD drive in UEFI mode or in Legacy?

Comment: @slm i've selected UEFI

Comment: Here's a guide ([Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/17531)) that covers how to do this using Ubuntu + Win8, but it applies for CentOS 6 as well.

Comment: @slm that helped a bit, i've created `/boot/efi` partition, i can open CentOS but only if i selected that in BIOS boot options. Not when i normally open my computer and select desired OS. If i don't enter the BIOS setting and select CentOS. I go to Windows directly.

Comment: See [my answer to “What should I do before dual-booting Windows 7 and Debian on EFI?”](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779). You can probably skip building a new kernel nowadays.