# How do I dual-boot 2 (or more) Linux distributions with gummiboot and UEFI?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have Arch installed as my main OS with `gummiboot` for booting. I'm planning to dual boot with Fedora 20 soon but I am currently held back by some doubts.

- Do I need to install Grub2 for Fedora even if `gummiboot` is already installed?

  - If I don't install Grub2, do I use `efibootmgr` from within Arch to add Fedora to the EFI boot entries?
- Is it okay to mount the EFS to `/boot/efi` instead of `/boot` (as it is on Arch)?
- For the `loader/entries/fedora.conf`, how do I specify the `linux` and `initrd` entries if my EFS is mounted to `/boot/efi` instead of in `/boot`?

  - This doubt arose because I initially installed Arch and opted to mount EFS to `/boot/efi` instead of `/boot`. In my `loader/entries/arch.conf` file, I had `linux` option set to `/vmlinuz-linux`. When I rebooted the system I got a big, fat **"cannot find vmlinuz-linux"** error. I re-installed and this time mounted EFS to `/boot` and everything booted fine using the same value for `linux`

I don't want to b0rk my boot setup as I have configured Arch to my liking (and don't want to re-install should I mess up). Off the top of my head, here's an approach I think might work.

1. Start Fedora 20 in live mode and run installer
2. Install Fedora **WITHOUT** a boot loader
3. `chroot` into the installed Fedora from live session (mounting the EFS to `/boot`) and...

   - copy Fedora's `vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs-linux.img`  to EFS (as soon as I find out where to get it from)
   - create `/boot/loader/entries/fedora-20.conf`
   - add an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount EFS to `/boot` on startup
4. Reboot (and cross fingers it doesn't b0rk the boot setup)

*Note: I did an `efibootmgr -v` in Arch and the entries are `Boot0000* Linux Boot Manager` (which I presume to be `gummiboot`) and `Boot0001* Hard Drive`. So I'm thinking that using `efibootmgr` isn't necessary, but I could be wrong.*

The above approach *may* work but I'm not sure it's optimal i.e. if Fedora 20 gets a kernel upgrade, then I'd probably have to copy  the new `vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs-linux.img` files to the ESP.

---

Some background: I used to have Debian Wheezy installed as my main OS and installed Arch for dual-boot, (both using UEFI booting). During my installation of Arch, I chose Grub2 instead of `gummiboot`. When I rebooted my PC, [Arch displayed it's Grub2 menu but failed to boot and then Debian's Grub2 displayed after](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104478/i-messed-up-my-efi-boot-what-do-i-do). So I knew I had 2 Grub2 menus chainloading and I didn't want that. I've since switched to Arch as my main OS using `gummiboot` and now want Fedora 20 for dual-boot. This time around, I don't want to mess up my boot options, hence this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can just arrange for completely separate ESPs and bootloaders provided that your firmware can do proper bootloader menu (or grub2 instances detect each other via os-prober and provide you with a boot path).